# rotate logs with logrotate and move old files

Tags: linux, log-files, syslog, logrotate

Logrotate don't move file to oldlogs folder and exit abnormally with code 1.
I tried to launch manually it with -d option but no errors are showed.
This is my configuration:

```
/var/log/myfolder/*.log
{
        rotate 4
        daily
        missingok
        size=100M
        notifempty
        copytruncate
        compress
        delaycompress
        create 640 root root
        dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                mv /var/log/myfolder/*.gz /var/log/myfolder/oldlogs/
                /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
        endscript
}
```

Any idea?

I have many files that are updated continuously and I would like to have the compressed files in another directory ( oldlogs) to storage purpose. Rotate command is unnecessary for my purpose but my problem is that I can't move files to oldlogs directory.

Comment: That `mv` is probably a bad idea.

Comment: What is the point of `rotate 4` if you just `mv` and overwrite the same filenames in `oldlogs` every day?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to move the old logs files yourself, log rotate does this for you.

You don't want to restart rsyslog in your `postrotate` script unless you're rotating logs being written from rsyslog. If that is the case, you don't need to perform a full restart of rsyslog, instead use `kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/rsyslogd.pid)` (assuming that's the pid of rsyslog).

The goal is to get the service to stop trying to write to the old file handler and start writing to the new log file.

If you're trying to logrotate a log written by another service, `-HUP` may not be supported.

What's the driver for using `copy truncate`? That's a bit exotic.

Further details are in the man page for `Logrotate` https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html

Comment: I want to move my compressed files to another directory. Logrotate keeps these files in same directory.

Comment: In that case you need the service writing the log file to stop writing to old log file before you try to move it. Try reordering your postrotate block.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need `-vf` if you want that logrotate runs `now`. `-d` disables any action, for details check `man logrotate`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need use full paths to `mv` along with the switch `-f` for force moves.

Comment: Is it really a good idea to overwrite your old logs every time?

Comment: Yes, if you need